# Applying a function that returns a dataframe gives broken result

Tags: pandas

My input is a dataframe and a function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'details': ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']})

def get_infos(x):
    if x == 'url1':
        return pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aaa'], 'col2': ['bbb']})
    
    elif x == 'url3':
        return pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['ccc'], 'col1': ['ddd']})
```

I don't have access to this function so I can change it. With the example I gave I tried to simulate it. It returns a dataframe based on a given url.

When I apply it to the column `details` I get unexpected result :

```
result = pd.concat([df, df['details'].apply(get_infos)], axis=1)

print(result)

#   details                  details
# 0    url1    col1 col2
# 0  aaa  bbb
# 1    url2                     None
# 2    url3    col3 col1
# 0  ccc  ddd
```

Do you guys know why ? Is there a solution to my problem ?

My expected output is this :

```
  details  col1  col2  col3
0    url1   aaa   bbb   NaN
1    url2   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    url3   ddd   NaN   ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function outputs a DataFrame, I wouldn't use `apply` here, rather go with a list comprehension and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df.join(pd.concat({i: get_infos(x) for i, x in df['details'].items()})
          .droplevel(1))
```

Output:

```
  details col1 col2
0    url1  aaa  bbb
1    url2  NaN  NaN
2    url3  ccc  ddd
```

Comment: I tested your solution on my example and real dataset and it worked. Thank you so much.